# OK to use a directive only as an UI component in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I am having an UI component which is reusable in multiple places. Therefore I have to duplicate the same css sections over several css files. Is it ok to create a directive for this scenario ? The directive will not process any js specific operations, it is there only for handling the UI component and avoid the duplication.

Comment: Components can carry their own CSS, which will only be applied to those components.  Would this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE:** You've specified “Angular” in the question title, but `angularjs` as a tag.  This answer assumes you're coding for Angular, not AngularJS.  Consider editing the tag or the question title to remove this ambiguity. ([*What’s the difference between AngularJS and Angular?*](https://gorrion.io/blog/angularjs-vs-angular/))

Angular can bundle style information with components.  You can specify the CSS:

1. inline using the `styles` attribute of the `@Component` decorator, or
2. in an external file using the `styleUrls` attribute of the `@Component` decorator.

See the [Component Styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) section of the Angular docs for examples & more info.

While you could technically write an [attribute directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) to style your component, why you would choose to do this instead of using the styling functionality provided by components is unclear.  Expanding your question with an example or two of what you're trying to achieve may bring you a better answer.